# Changing the BadgeValue from a UISplitViewController 's detail view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

The main view of my iPad app is a **TabBarController**. Each Tab contains a **UISplitViewController**.

The **UISplitViewController** contains **UINavigationControllers**.

How do I change the tab's **BadgeValue** from a **ViewController** located within a **UISplitViewController**.

I've tried setting the TabBarItem property of the ViewController but there is no effect.

Strangely the UIViewContoller's NavigationController and SplitViewController property's are null even though the UIViewContoller is in a NavigationController  which is in a SplitViewController .

Summary: The Heirarchy looks like this:

```
 tabbar
   splitview
       navigation
          viewcontroller
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

A TabBarController's tabbar is accessed by the direct child, in this case the SplitController.

Because the SplitController doesn't get loaded until the tab is pressed, you have to set the badge when you create the tabbarcontroller (a custom one).

```
theSplitController.TabBarItem.BadgeValue = items.Count().ToString();
```